# What should be the name of the file to give html output?

Tags: html

How should I save my html document to give an html output that will open in my browser?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: use .html or .htm extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gs` files can't be used as `html` files in Apps script. The html file should end with `.html`. Such files can be created with File > New > Html file.